# Asp.Net Core Razor Pages: asp-route to use value from input on same page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

From an Index page, is it possible to get the text value from an input like this:

```
<input id="inpSearchMembers" class="form-control small-text" placeholder="Search for a Member..." />
```

and feed it into the `asp-route-searchText` attribute value in something like this:

```
<a id="btnSearchMembers" class="btn btn-outline-primary small-text" asp-page="/Search" asp-route-searchText="~Value from InpSearchMember~" >Search</a>
```

So that the attribute `asp-route-searchText` contains the text of the input field `id="inpSearchMembers"` before sending back to the code-behind when clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `asp-route-...` will be used by the `AnchorTagHelper` to render the attribute `href` ***once*** and ***statically*** without any magic binding like what you wish for. So for example, if you have a route pattern like `/abc/{searchText}`. After being rendered to HTML, the `A` element will have its `href` rendered like `/abc/whatever-from-asp-route-searchText`. I would not try to send value via route data in such use cases if possible. But if you have to, you need to use javascript here to replace the `searchText` (initially rendered as a unique token inside the `href`) with the ***dynamic*** value from the other `input` before the link is visited by clicking.

First you prepare the code in the razor view like this:

```
@{
   var searchToken = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
}
<a id="btnSearchMembers" class="btn btn-outline-primary small-text" 
   asp-page="/Search" asp-route-searchText="@searchToken">Search</a>
```

Next, you write code for the javascript part to replace the search token with runtime (dynamic) value from the other input:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var searchLink = document.getElementById("btnSearchMembers");
    var originalHref = searchLink.href;
    searchLink.onclick = function(e){
       //get the value from the other input and replace the link's href 
       //before it's visited by the link click.
       var searchTextElement = document.getElementById("inpSearchMembers");
       e.target.href = originalHref.replace("@searchToken", searchTextElement.value);  
    };
}
```

Of course the above `javascript` code should be written in the same razor view file so that you can access to the server variable `searchToken`.

Comment: This is great, and makes sense so thanks, I have learned something today! I have since found the best way to do this is to use a form submit technique. This is great to see working though so thank you again!

Comment: @CJH you're welcome, yes using form is good however the point here is how you send the *dynamic* data, it should be directly from a form field/element instead of having to be put in a route value (forming the request path). By forming the request path, it's convenient only when that value is not taken from users or you have non-browser clients. For browser clients, we should use HTML forms.

Comment: Brill, that makes sense...! This is all very good to understand so thank you again!

Comment: In the part where you use `asp-route-searchText`, is it possible to make the `seachText` dynamic as well? Something like `asp-route-@(searchRoute)`?

Comment: @AndresElizondo that syntax is not supported. The `AnchorTagHelper` (as well as any other kinds of `TagHelper`) has properties ***predefined*** and their names are based on ***literal*** text at design time. If the razor page code can be dynamically generated, then you can write it that way. However you can use `asp-all-route-data` to specify a route data dictionary instead and it's completely dynamic, like this: `asp-all-route-data="@(new Dictionary<string,string> { [searchRoute] = "someValue" })"`

Comment: That's perfect!! Thank you @KingKing! Very well explained as well, I appreciate it!